# Problem sending MetaCoin from one account to another using unit test

Tags: truffle

In Truffle; I am trying to modify the already existing *MetaCoin* sample unit test in order to better understand how everything works. Below is the unit test they provide which transfers 10 coins from `account[0]` to `account[1]` which passes.

```
  it("should send coin correctly", function() {
    var meta;

    //    Get initial balances of first and second account.
    var account_one = accounts[0];
    var account_two = accounts[1];

    var account_one_starting_balance;
    var account_two_starting_balance;
    var account_one_ending_balance;
    var account_two_ending_balance;

    var amount = 10;

    return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      meta = instance;
      return meta.getBalance.call(account_one);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      account_one_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return meta.getBalance.call(account_two);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      account_two_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return meta.sendCoin(account_two, amount, {from: account_one});
    }).then(function() {
      return meta.getBalance.call(account_one);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      account_one_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();
      return meta.getBalance.call(account_two);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      account_two_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

      assert.equal(account_one_ending_balance, account_one_starting_balance - amount, "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender");
      assert.equal(account_two_ending_balance, 10, "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender");
    });
  });
```

I created a second unit test; where I wanted to transfer 5 coins out of account[1] and transfer it to account[2]; however, my test always returns 0.

```
  it("should send some more coins!", function() {
      var amount = 5;
      var meta;
      var account_two = accounts[1];
      var account_three = accounts[2];

      return MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) {
        meta = instance;
        return instance.sendCoin.call(account_three, amount, {from: account_two});
    }).then(function(balance) {
      return meta.getBalance.call(account_three);
    }).then(function(balance) {
      assert.equal(balance.toNumber(), amount, "Amount equaled 5 as expected");
    });
  })
```

When I run it; the unit test results are this:

Contract: MetaCoin
    √ should put 10000 MetaCoin in the first account
    √ should call a function that depends on a linked library (68ms)
    √ should send coin correctly (156ms)
    1) should send some more coins!

3 passing (390ms)
  1 failing

1) Contract: MetaCoin should send some more coins!:
     **AssertionError: Amount equaled 5 as expected: expected 0 to equal 5**
      at C:/Dev/Blockchain/test/metacoin.js:92:14
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Comment: I think it should be `instance.sendCoin(account_three, amount, {from: acccount_two});`, ie without `call`.

Comment: @Ismael - Ahh... that was it!  Thank you!  Can you tell me, what is the .call function used for and when do you know when to use it?  Is call a Truffle or Solidity function?

Also--if you want to put this as the answer, I will mark it for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be

```
instance.sendCoin(account_three, amount, {from: acccount_two});
```

ie without the `call` part.

It is used to differentiate when you are calling a constant method vs calling a non-constant method. I think it is from web3 which is the library that interact with your geth/parity node.

Constant methods do not use gas when being called (they do not generate a transaction), they cannot modify the contract storage, and they can return a value as a result of the operation.

Non-constant methods use gas when invoked (ie they generate a transaction in the blockchain), and can modify your contract storage, the usually will not return value as a result.